# Can I print on a plastic sheet using a laser printer?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I want to print some lines on a plastic sheet (for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfynPd2PW0Y)) using a laser jet printer (to be more specific, a HP M1005 MFP). I suspect it might burn when I try to print. Should I print or not? Or should I buy printable sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some special acetate sheets for laser printing that resist the heat of the printer.

They were very common before the era of cheaper lcd projectors.

https://www.google.com/search?q=acetate+laser+print

Comment: Even though I've used acetate sheets for making screens more recently.. just the mention of projectors and acetate sheets brings back memories of those massive overhead projectors in school!

Comment: My era of projections in school was 35 mm slides :o)

Answer (score 0):

what I do is use laminator sheets.
laminate the empty sheet then use it in the printer
don't use the sheet unlaminated or it will separate the top and bottom sheets and the glue will make the sheet wrap around the hot roller which takes a lot of work to remove.